# How to implement expected exceptions?

Tags: exception, behat

I am trying my first features with Behat and I am facing the problem I don't know how to implement expected exceptions.

I found the issue https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/140 and robocoder is talking about one possible way, which is used by Behat, too. But it seems that they aren't really handling exceptions.

My point is to achieve forced exception handling. I don't want any construct catching all exceptions and forget them.

One possible way would be:

```
When <player> transfers <transfer> from his account it should fail with <error>
```

Implementation

```
try {
    ...
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    assertEquals($error, $ex->getMessage());
}
```

I don't like the scenario description. I want to use the **then** keyword, e.g.

```
When <player> transfers <transfer> from his account
Then it should fail with error <error>
```

This description has the disadvantage I need two methods:

```
method1($arg1, $arg2) {
    // Test the transfer
}

method2($arg1, $arg2) {
    // Check if the exception is the right one
}
```

To be able to check in **method2** the exception needs to be stored.
The only possible way I see is to use a try/catch and store it to a variable.
Someone else would catch it and do nothing with it. Nobody will notice, when running the tests.

How can I prevent that exceptions are discarded?
Has anybody else a similar scenario implemented?

Thanks for any hints.

**EDIT**:

Behat context:

```
playerTransfer($player, $amount) {      
    $player->transfer($amount);
}
```

Method from entity class:

```
transfer($amount) {
    if ($this->getWealth() < $amount) {
        throw NotEnoughMoney();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always try to catch method outcome to context class field, for example:

```
//inside Behat context class method  
try {
  $this->outcome = $func();
}
catch(\Exception $ex) {
  $this->outcome = $ex;
}
```

Now when expecting exception at next step just check if $this->outcome is instanceof desired exception with message/code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your implementation. Do you check if transfer is successful in "When  transfers  from his account" ? Do you need to check it ?

Failure test:

```
When <player> transfers <transfer> from his account
Then I should see error <error>
```

Successful step:

```
When <player> transfers <transfer> from his account
Then I should see "transfer successful"
```

Comment: How do you handle exceptions thrown by *<player> transfers <transfer> from his account*? See the second part of my question.

Comment: it should not throw exception, exception should be thrown in "Then i should ...". Could you post some pseudo implementation ?

Comment: Added some implementation. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: You are doing two things in single step. Check for available money should not be in transfer step. You should have 3 steps: 1) I transfer xxx money 2) I should see message that transfer is successful 3) I should see message that transfer is unsuccessful

Comment: Do you mean it is wrong in the Behat context or in general?

Comment: I think it is wrong. I don't know your business logic. You could check some of everzet videos.

Comment: You can see a part of the business logic above. Which videos do you mean exactly? I just found some about TDD.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I successfully did it in a project of mine where I had to repeat a few steps till the condition held true:

```
/**
* @Given /^I execute some conditions$/
*/
public function executeConditions()
{
   $flag = 1;
    do {
        try {
            <steps to be executed till the condition holds true>
            $flag=1;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            $flag = 0;
        }
    }while ($flag>0);
 }
```